# nginx reverse-proxy upgrade from nginx 1.17 to nginx 1.18 gives SSL error

Tags: nginx, iis, reverse-proxy

I am having trouble upgrading nginx from 1.17 to 1.18 (or .19, .20)
Everything works ok on 1.17, but higher versions give this error:

```
2021/08/27 01:14:45 [error] 22#22: *8 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 192.168.**.**, server: api*******.hm.*******.gov.br, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://192.168.**.**:443/favicon.ico", host: "api*******.hm.********.gov.br"
```

The error only happens when upstream is a internal IIS server.
When upstream is another nginx it works with versions above 1.17

config is basically:

```
location  / {
    proxy_pass https://$host.***.br$uri$is_args$args;
```

I tried to use `proxy_ssl_verify off` without success.
IIS certificate is self-generated.

Please advise

Comment: Have you tried to add `proxy_ssl_server_name on;`?

Comment: Yes . I have. Same error

Comment: Then it's most probably what Tero Kilkanen has said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem with TLS versions. Maybe your backend IIS server isn't new enough to support TLS protocol that nginx requires?

Try adding `proxy_ssl_protocols` directive that contains the SSL / TLS versions your IIS supports.

Comment: Thanks, Will try that. Any means to debug  those protocols strings exchange?

Comment: I have added `proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1;`  (and not TLSv2) to location block and it accepted IIS 8.5 Ciphers (IIS running on W2012r2).  Then I will accept the answer because it has taken me off of the error condition. BUT, best approach would be to upgrade IIS to support TLSv2 and I will work on that config too.